# chef-server-ctl reconfigure fails RHEL7

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, rhel7

Trying to install chef-server on my RHEL7 laptop and getting the following:

```
    Recipe: private-chef::postgresql
  * execute[/opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start postgresql] action run
    - execute /opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start postgresql
  * ruby_block[wait for postgresql to start] action runpsql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[2017-04-02T13:07:02+02:00] FATAL: Could not connect to database, retrying in 10 seconds.
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[2017-04-02T13:07:32+02:00] FATAL: Could not connect to database, retrying in 10 seconds.
[2017-04-02T13:08:02+02:00] FATAL: 
Could not connect to the postgresql database.
Please check /var/log/opscode/posgresql/current for more information.
```

/tmp status:

```
  File: ‘/tmp’
  Size: 620         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 25h/37d Inode: 11926       Links: 18
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0
Access: 2017-04-02 13:05:31.820289046 +0200
Modify: 2017-04-02 13:12:19.714572010 +0200
Change: 2017-04-02 13:12:19.714572010 +0200
 Birth: -
```

log file is empty even though it has full permission..

Comment: Is Postgres running?

Comment: ps aux | grep post
root     23611  0.0  0.0   4176   436 ?        Ss   12:59   0:12 runsv postgresql
opscode  23612  0.0  0.0   4320   544 ?        S    12:59   0:01 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/postgresql/9.2

down: postgresql: 1s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 23612) 18618s
run: rabbitmq: (pid 19511) 18659s; run: log: (pid 19510) 18659s

Comment: So, no. Figure out why that is.

Comment: Sorry don't get what you meant..

Comment: If the PostgreSQL server isn't running, then you can't connect to it. Figure out why it isn't starting correctly.

Comment: Well I have nowhere to start from, empty log file and the error message above, which could mean everything, I have selinux disabled, /tmp full permissions and no reason as to why chef can't start postgresql

Comment: Try starting the service and see what happens? `chef-server-ctl start postgresql` or something like that.

Comment: sudo chef-server-ctl start postgresql
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 23567) 0s

Comment: - execute /opt/opscode/bin/private-chef-ctl start postgresql
  * ruby_block[wait for postgresql to start] action runpsql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[2017-04-02T19:53:26+02:00] FATAL: Could not connect to database, retrying in 10 seconds.

Tried to touch the sock and chmod it still no play.

Comment: Please stop pasting large chunks of output in comments, there is no formatting here. But go see if it actually started correctly and debug from there. Normal Postgres debugging rules apply.

Comment: Sorry about the big chunks, it starts normally without a problem, problem is sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure, it can't start/connect to postgresql and I don't know a thing about it except it's just db like mysql or something, and usually if it was mysql, the sock file permission would've done the trick, so I don't know how to fix this, if you have a tip I would appreciate that.